# Distance queries on Tree with hotspots

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures, trees

We are given a tree with $n$ vertices and some of the vertices act as a "hotspot".

We have to answer multiple queries of type $(a,b,c)$, which means we have to find the distance to the nearest hotspot from $c$ such that we do not travel through the edge between nodes $a$ and $b$.

I have tried many data structures like using lowest common ancestor and algorithms like mo's algorithm on a tree, I have also tried to process queries which are closer to root first, but none of these have given me the desired complexity for each query which is anywhere between $O(1)$ to $O(\log n)$.

Is there any better algorithm or perhaps some clever precomputation(in less time than $O(n\log n)$ that can be used to solve this problem?

Comment: can you aid your question with  a graph diagram, showing the query on a example graph?

Comment: If we process the queries for each `(a, b)` in order, can we have an `O(log n)` update procedure to add that edge back in and remove the next, updating all relevant distances?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [top-tree](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/1103963.1103966) data structure.
It maintains a forest $F$ on $n$ nodes and supports (among others) each of the following operations in $O(\log n)$ time per operation:

- Given an unmarked vertex $v$ mark $v$.
- Given a marked vertex $v$ unmark $v$.
- Given two vertices $u,v$ that belong to two different trees in $F$, add the edge $(u,v)$ to $F$ (thus merging two trees into one).
- Given an edge $(u,v)$ of a tree in $F$, delete $(u,v)$ from $F$ (thus splitting the three into two).
- Given a vertex $v$, report the distance to the marked vertex that belongs to the tree of $v$ and is closest to $v$.

This allows you to preprocess your tree in time $O(n \log n)$: build the forest $F$ on $n$ nodes by adding the edges of the tree one by one (so that, at the end, $F$ contains the input tree), then mark each hotspot.

To answer a query $(a,b,c)$ in time $O(\log n)$ proceed as follows:

- Delete $(a,b)$ from $F$ in time $O(\log n)$.
- Find the distance $d$ to the marked vertex that is closest to $c$. This takes $O(\log n)$ time and is exactly the answer to the query.
- Re-add $(a,b)$ to $F$ in time $O(\log n)$.
- Return $d$.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how to process the query?

Comment: I expanded that part of the answer. Is it clearer now?

Comment: I don't understand how to find the closest marks vertex to c in log(n) as each vertex in the top-tree represents and edge so there is no notion of an edge being marked  and unmarked

Comment: Each vertex of the original tree is a vertex in the top tree. Each edge of the original tree is an edge in the top tree. In other words, the forest $F$ maintained by the top-tree contains only one tree which is exactly your input tree.

Comment: I tried reading some papers on top-tree and couldn't understand some terminologies such as ∂T, and external boundary vertices. Is there in a resource that explains this complex data-structure such that a novice like me can understand?

Answer (score 1):

Merge all hotspots into a single node $h$ (Instead of a tree - the input is now an undirected graph). The problem can now be represented as follows:

Given an undirected graph $G$ and a node $h$ (the merged hotspot), we want to answer queries $Q(c, e)$:

$Q(c, e)$: Given node $c\in G$ and edge $e\in G$, return $\mathrm{distance}(h, c)$ in $G\setminus \{e\}$.

This is a dynamic problem, or more specifically: an *edge-decremental single-source shortest-path distance problem* (also called *single-source edge-removal exact distance oracle*).

In [[1](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0097539705429847)], the preprocessing time is $O(mn^{1.5} + n^{2.5} \log n)$ and the query time is $O(1)$. This is an All-Pairs Shortest Paths algorithm, while you require only a single-source algorithm.

[[2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.00190)] improves the results to $O(\sigma^{0.5}\cdot n^{1.5})$ preprocessing time and $O(1)$ query time. $\sigma$ is the number of sources (in your case: $\sigma=1$ - the merged hotspot).

Following [[2](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.00190)], you can get an $O(n^{1.5})$ preprocessing time and $O(1)$ query time using $O(n^{1.5})$ memory.

Comment: I don't understand how can one consider all hotspots as a single node

Comment: Since you don't care which hotspot you reach, and since once a hotspot is reached - you're done, nothing prevents you from regarding them all as the same node. This is an equivalent graph you need either to construct or process the tree as it was such.

Comment: Also note that the equivalent problem is reversed: reach c from the 'united hotspot' instead of reaching any hotspot from c.

Comment: OP wrote "distance to the *nearest* hotspot."

Comment: @גלעדברקן: Yes.... that's in line with my answer. Why do you think it is not so? (re my note above: we don't care which hotspot to reach as long as it is the nearest hotspot).

Comment: I guess I'm not clear enough. I refer to a node in the graph. The graph is constructed by merging all hotspots in the tree into a single node.

Comment: Cool, yeah, maybe a few words on why that construction is useful would help, but I suppose it's in the articles.